# Who are the Steam Mascots?

Tags: steam

So with the Steam Summer Sale in full swing, I've finally taken notice of the Steam Mascots.

Judging by the latest background, the black one, at least, has a name: Cyl.

Do the other two have names as well? Are there only these three?

What's their story?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the [Steam forums](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=18965732&postcount=11):

> The black mascot name is [CyL](http://steamcommunity.com/id/IAmTheMaster)
>   the yellow is [Sir Roderick Bodkins](http://steamcommunity.com/id/SirRoderickBodkin)
>   the orange is [Tappet](http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198010105057).

They have steam accounts, but they aren't in use (almost 1k days without logging in). As far as back-story or explanation, there isn't any that I know of.

Comment: Are those official Steam Accounts, or just some enterprising individual?

Comment: They are normally claimed to be official on the forums. My opinion is that if someone who wasn't Steam bothered to register all the names, they would have made an amusing post or two. So I believe they are official (placeholders), but I can't confirm that.

Comment: Good enough for me; especially since they were created within an hour of each other.

Comment: By the way, some other ones did appear last year, a purple one, a green one...i think some others too. Those were never given names and didn't show up more than a couple times. I think we are to understand that these are the main characters, but not necessarily the only ones of their kind.

Comment: I don't, sorry. On today's steam Summer Camp group page there is confirmation of CyL's name though.

Comment: Here's an [image](http://www.blogcdn.com/www.joystiq.com/media/2010/11/gamsteamsalemonsters530.jpg) with the additional mascots that showed up for the halloween sale. Couldn't find whether or not they actually have names, though.